# Pass boolean as param in Java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have two classes in my main android app's class file. It's main activity and AsyncTask. I'm passing username and password strings when calling AsyncTask, but I want to pass an boolean from main activity together with strings. I'll explain it in code below (please check comments in code):

```
//I have an main class
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    boolean clicked = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //stuff

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    //DO something
                    clicked = true;
                    AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                    runner.execute(getUsername(), getPassword()); //Here I want to pass boolean clicked, which will be checked on asynctask!
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        if clicked == true{
        //do something
        }else{
        //do something        
    }
  }
}
```

This is probably not so complicated question to someone who works with Java often, I don't so that's why I'm asking...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it as one of the strings in the array:

```
runner.execute(String.valueOf(clicked), getUsername(), getPassword());
```

And the AsyncTask will fetch it:

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        boolean clicked = Boolean.parseBoolean(strings[0]);
        String user = strings[1];
        String pass = strings[2];
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. AsyncTaskRunner is Non-static Inner class of MyActivity class so You Already have access to 'clicked' field of Activity in any AsyncTaskRunner instance methods. You don't need to do anything in order to be able to see 'clicked' field in AsyncTaskRunner methods.
2. If you declare AsyncTaskRunner is Static class. Here is the code:

   ```
   private static class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

       private final boolean clicked;

       //private final Object anotherParams;

       public AsyncTaskRunner(boolean clicked ) {
           this.clicked = clicked;
       }

       public boolean isClicked() {
           return clicked;
       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

       }
   }
   ```
3. Use AsyncTaskRunner

   ```
   AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner(MyActivity.this.clicked);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

create a constructor for your `AsyncTaskRunner` class and pass your parameters to constructor and then use them in `AsyncTaskRunner` class methods.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. But how to I pass boolean? Can you check code please and give me some code examples? Thanks!